# Using AND condition in decode

Tags: sql, oracle, case, decode

I have a scenario where I need to check the date and a value to determine the result.

Ex-

```
case when my_date > '10-01-2011' and my_value = 0 then
'Do this'
else 
'Do that'
end
```

I'm trying to use this in oracle SQL query, I was wondering if there is a better approach to this logic rather than using case statement; perhaps using decode or any other oracle function.

Comment: This is perfectly fine, decode will complicate it and cannot be used with *greater than*

Comment: `case when then` case expression is a part of ANSII SQL standard and is supported by almost all DBMS. `Decode` works on Oracle, but you can't find this function on remaining leading DBMS systems - PostgreSQL, SQL-Server, MySql, SQLite etc. I recommend you to use case expressions instead of DECODE.

Comment: In addition to the previous comments (stick with CASE, not DECODE), what is the datatype of the my_date column? If it's of DATE datatype, then don't compare it to a string - instead, explicitly convert the string into a date using either `to_date()` with the appropriate format mask (e.g. `to_date('10-01-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy')`) or (if there's no time element to your date value) using the `DATE` literal (e.g. `DATE '2011-01-10'`).

Comment: Decode is a poor man's case when...

Comment: Totally agree that `case` is the best approach, and `decode` is a poor substitute.  But for info it is possible to perform *greater than* logic using a combination of `decode` and `sign`: `decode(sign(my_date - date '2011-01-10'), 1, 'yes', 'no') as is_greater`

Answer (score 5):

`CASE` is the ANSI SQL standard for conditional logic in SQL.  Your code is therefore fine except for the string '10-01-2011' which you are treating implicitly as a date.  I would use the ANSI `DATE` literal format for this:

```
case when my_date > date '2011-01-10' and my_value = 0 then
  'Do this'
else 
  'Do that'
end
```

`DECODE` was Oracle's proprietary solution to conditional SQL before `CASE` was available.  The same logic could be expressed using `DECODE` like this:

```
decode (my_value,
        0, decode (sign (my_date - date '2011-01-10'), 
                   1, 
                   'Do this',
                   'Do that'),
        'Do that')
```

Not very elegant or readable is it?  It also uses the `SIGN` function, which returns 1 for a positive number, -1 for negative, and 0 for 0.

Note also that `CASE` can be used in PL/SQL whereas `DECODE` cannot.

```
-- This works
myvar := case when x=1 then 'a' else 'b' end;
-- This doesn't
myvar := decode (x, 1, 'a', 'b');
```

Comment: Good explanation.  I especially like the use of `date`.